# Foreach table output rows near each other

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have json html table in php, now i can't get it work that the output in the table will be near each other.

I am already few days busy with this, hope some one can help me.

```
  <?php  foreach($data2 as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['model'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['model2'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

[image]

My json output:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with near each other? in the same column or show the existing one?

Comment: The left side data need up.

Comment: you can try to get each one of the values as a separate array using array_column function and then do foreach on the longest array length $model = array_column($yourjsonarray, 'model'); $model2 = array_column($yourjsonarray, 'model2'); be careful with undefined index you need to check if the index exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JSON is not formatted for what you are trying to do. Every object has either modal or modal2, so the one that is not filled is undefined.

You should get the length of the longest list and use a normal for loop.

```
<?php ($index = 0; $index <= $lengthOfLongestList; $index++): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$data2[index]['model'];?></td>
        <td><?=$data2[index]['model2'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I now make this:   
<?php $model = array_column($data2, 'model');
        $model2 = array_column($data2, 'model2');
  ?>  
  
  <?php  foreach($model as $index => $value) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$model[$index];?></td>
            <td><?=$model2[$index];?></td>
        </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>

It work's, how i make lengthOfLongestList?

Comment: $lengthOfModel = count($model); $lengthOfModel2 = count($model2); $lengthOfLongestList = $lengthOfModel > $lengthOfModel2 ? $lengthOfModel : $lengthOfModel2;